# React Native component briefly renders before the animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I have a `react-native` component which runs an animation using `react-native-reaniamted`.

You can find the snack [here.](https://snack.expo.io/@griffintaimer/3ca422)

**Problem:**

The component briefly blinks before the animation kicks in, causing bad user experience. I think the issue is in the following line, which sets the `strokeDashoffset` value, but not sure how to fix it.

```
const strokeDashoffset = sub(circumference, multiply(α, r));
```

I can confirm that when the animation starts, the value of `α` is zero and hence the value of `strokeDashoffset` is also 0, which should hide the circle, but it is not doing so.